# IIS 7.5 application pool's config file is missing

Tags: iis-7.5, application-pool

I have a windows 2008 R2 server which has an IIS installed on it.
The server was fine when suddenly today I had an error occurred on it. The service that was using this application pool was unavailable (Error 503), and when I opened the IIS manager I saw that the application pool was stopped.
When viewed the Event Viewer of Windows, I've noticed that in the application logs there were errors from a source of "IIS-W3SVC-WP" which of course caught my eyes.
I read the logs and in the logs the details said that the config file of the application pool is missing:

```
The worker process for application pool 'HealthCheck' encountered an error
'Cannot read configuration file' trying to read configuration file
'\\?\C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\HealthCheck\HealthCheck.config', line number '0'.
The data field contains the error code
```

The event ID was 2307, and according to the error, there is a problem in line 0 of the configuration file, so when I tried to open this file, I found out that this file doesn't exist at all, so it means that there is no configuration file for the application pool as opposed of the data in the Event Viewer.
Needless to say that there was no data elsewhere on the Event Viewer. When I've searched the Internet, all I could find was errors related to other lines in the configuration file (Which means that the configuration file problematic itself).

Did somebody encountered this error before?
What should I do when I can't event debug this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today with DefaultAppPool. The error was referencing C:\inetpub\temp\appPools\DefaultAppPool\DefaultAppPool.config. When I went to look at the file, it wasn't there and the directory DefaultAppPool wasn't there either.

I took a look at another server that wasn't having this issue and found the directory and config file were there.

I also noticed that when I started the app pool a file was created in C:\inetpub\temp\appPools, in my case it was called APC1B60.tmp. I looked at that file in notepad and it's a config file. So I saved that file as C:\inetpub\temp\appPools\DefaultAppPool\DefaultAppPool.config. I started the app pool and everything is running as expected.

I'm not sure what happened to delete the file in the first place or what the correct way to recreate it is, but this worked for me.